# Ouput function result of calculation to multiple Cells in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

Im using VBA to program a function in excel that will search a list looking for certain names, count when certain sought for names come up and then output these counter values to individual cells.

How do I allocate the values to the function itself when I have a multi cell function? Ive chosen 4 cells next to each other in the same column and pressed CTRL-SHFT-ENTER to get a multi cell function I just dont know how to allocate results to the function so that it will show in the selected cells. What I've done so far is shown below:

```
Function ROM(ByVal lookup_value As Range, _
ByVal lookup_column As Range, _
ByVal return_value_column As Long) As String 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim resultCount As Long
Dim resultsArray() As String
Dim arraySize As Long
Dim myrange As Range
Dim results As String
Dim TSS As Long
Dim OSS As Long
Dim AWS As Long
Dim JLI As Long
Dim answers(1 To 3, 1 To 1) As Variant


' The following code works out how many matches there are for the lookup and creates an
' array of the same size to hold these results

Set myrange = lookup_column
arraySize = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange, lookup_value.Value)
ReDim resultsArray(arraySize - 1)

' A counter for the results

resultCount = 0
TSS = 0
OSS = 0
AWS = 0
JLI = 0

' The equipment ID column is looped through and for every match the corresponding Equipment Type is
' saved into the resultsArray for analysis

For i = 1 To lookup_column.Rows.count
    If Len(lookup_column(i, 1).Text) <> 0 Then
        If lookup_column(i, 1).Text = lookup_value.Value Then

                ' If statement to ensure that the function doesnt cycle to a number larger than the
                ' size of resultsArray

                If (resultCount < (arraySize)) Then
                    resultsArray(resultCount) = (lookup_column(i).Offset(0, return_value_column).Text)
                    results = (lookup_column(i).Offset(0, return_value_column).Text)
                    resultCount = resultCount + 1
                        ' The following code compares the string to preset values and increments
                        ' the counters if any are found in the string

                        If (InStr(results, "TPWS TSS") > 0) Then
                            TSS = TSS + 1

                        ElseIf (InStr(results, "TPWS OSS")) Then
                            OSS = OSS + 1

                        ElseIf (InStr(results, "JUNCTION INDICATOR (1 Route)") > 0) Then
                            JLI = JLI + 1

                        ElseIf (InStr(results, "AWS")) Then
                            AWS = AWS + 1

                        End If

                 End If
        End If
    End If
Next

 answers(1, 1) = TSS
 answers(1, 2) = OSS
 answers(1, 3) = AWS
 answers(1, 4) = 0

  ROM = answers    


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Function
```

When I try running the function it keeps saying type mismatch for answers. The cells selected for the multi cell formula are F18, G18, H18 and I18.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To return array functions from VBA

1. your function must be of type Variant
2. your output array must match the selected range - in your case it must be 1-dimensional 
   whereas you are dimensioning a 2-dimensional array

Try this

```
Function MyArray() As Variant
Dim Tmp(3) As Variant

    Tmp(0) = 1
    Tmp(1) = "XYZ"
    Tmp(2) = 3
    Tmp(3) = 4

    MyArray = Tmp

End Function
```

Now select F18..I18, enter =MyArray() and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This may vary depending on the version of Excel you are using.  I am using the Office2003 suite and the solutions presented above do not work with this version of Excel.

I find that you need a two diminsion array output to Excel with the values in the second diminsion.

I'll borrow MikeD's example above and modify it to work in Excel2003.

```
Function MyArray() As Variant
Dim Tmp() As Variant

redim Tmp(3,0) as Variant

Tmp(0,0) = 1
Tmp(1,0) = "XYZ"
Tmp(2,0) = 3
Tmp(3,0) = 4

MyArray = Tmp

End Function
```

Note that you can re-diminsion your array to use a dynamic output, but you must select a large enough range to encompass all of your output when you insert the function into Excel.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're getting the type mismatch because you're trying to assign the result to a String. If you assign to a Variant you'll avoid that problem.

Second, your `answers` array should be dimensioned as:

`Dim answers(3) As Variant`

The following code should work for you if I've understood the problem correctly.

```
Function ROM(ByVal lookup_value As Range, _
ByVal lookup_column As Range, _
ByVal return_value_column As Long) As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim resultCount As Long
Dim resultsArray() As String
Dim arraySize As Long
Dim myrange As Range
Dim results As String
Dim TSS As Long
Dim OSS As Long
Dim AWS As Long
Dim JLI As Long
Dim answers(3) As Variant


' The following code works out how many matches there are for the lookup and creates an
' array of the same size to hold these results

Set myrange = lookup_column
arraySize = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange, lookup_value.Value)
ReDim resultsArray(arraySize - 1)

' A counter for the results

resultCount = 0
TSS = 0
OSS = 0
AWS = 0
JLI = 0

' The equipment ID column is looped through and for every match the corresponding Equipment Type is
' saved into the resultsArray for analysis

For i = 1 To lookup_column.Rows.Count
    If Len(lookup_column(i, 1).Text) <> 0 Then
        If lookup_column(i, 1).Text = lookup_value.Value Then

                ' If statement to ensure that the function doesnt cycle to a number larger than the
                ' size of resultsArray

                If (resultCount < (arraySize)) Then
                    resultsArray(resultCount) = (lookup_column(i).Offset(0, return_value_column).Text)
                    results = (lookup_column(i).Offset(0, return_value_column).Text)
                    resultCount = resultCount + 1
                        ' The following code compares the string to preset values and increments
                        ' the counters if any are found in the string

                        If (InStr(results, "TPWS TSS") > 0) Then
                            TSS = TSS + 1

                        ElseIf (InStr(results, "TPWS OSS")) Then
                            OSS = OSS + 1

                        ElseIf (InStr(results, "JUNCTION INDICATOR (1 Route)") > 0) Then
                            JLI = JLI + 1

                        ElseIf (InStr(results, "AWS")) Then
                            AWS = AWS + 1

                        End If

                 End If
        End If
    End If
Next

 answers(0) = TSS
 answers(1) = OSS
 answers(2) = AWS
 answers(3) = 0

  ROM = answers


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Function
```